# Retreiving selected text from chrome PDF viewer in chrome extension background.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I have managed to retrieve highlighted text from the chrome PDF viewer using a contextMenu with the "selection" context -

**Background.js:**

```
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: "text_save",
        title: "Save text",
        contexts: ["selection"],
        onclick: function (info) {
            var text = info.selectionText;
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"message": "text", "text": text});
            }
        });
```

But I have been unsuccessful so far in retrieving highlighted text from the PDF viewer in any other way (specifically, using getSelection() from either background or context.js on both "document" and "window")

Is there a way to imitate the actions of the contextMenu (without having to use one) in retrieving the highlighted text? Where does the contextMenu run its function to be able to access the highlighted text of the PDF viewer extension?

---**Edit**---

Found this source regarding an API in the chrome PDF viewer - https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/wn49iiOt7iY

the source code - chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/pdf.js

Is this code callable? I've tried sending "getSelectedText" to the PDF extension, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: In Chrome PDF viewer is a *plugin* so DOM methods don't work inside its container. ContextMenu method is a built-in chrome API so the browser passes the text directly.

Comment: getSelectedText works only in the built-in PDF viewer companion extension that handles the tab UI, see [the source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_scripting_api.js?l=57&rcl=5c722a0454c3a7daabecfce31dd9647883cad308). You can probably "hack" into the extension by using chrome.debugger API to attach to the extension context in the tab and do `window.postMessage` on behalf of its content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm any chance you can provide some example code?